# Database connection working well in Android Studio VDM but not in phone

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I am making a listview that loads the names in the database. And CustomerID is used to access the detail view of a name.
I am getting the output in Android Studio VDM without any problems. But when i run it on my phone (Android 4.3), the following error appears.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference at com.tut.app.GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter.getCount(GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter.java:38)

My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView GetAllCustomerListView;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.GetAllCustomerListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.GetAllCustomerListView);

        new GetAllCustomerTask().execute(new ApiConnector());

        this.GetAllCustomerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try
                {
                    // GEt the customer which was clicked
                    JSONObject customerClicked = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);

                    // Send Customer ID
                    Intent showDetails = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CustomerDetailsActivity.class);
                    showDetails.putExtra("CustomerID", customerClicked.getInt("id"));

                    startActivity(showDetails);

                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }



    public  void setListAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
        this.GetAllCustomerListView.setAdapter(new GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter(jsonArray,this));
    }




    private class GetAllCustomerTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray>
    {
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {

            // it is executed on Background thread

             return params[0].GetAllCustomers();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

            setListAdapter(jsonArray);


        }
    }

}
```

Please Help! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out whats wrong! :D
My Laptop was connected to the Localhost. So, it had no problems in running the app. But only when I hosted the php files and database in the server, the app worked in the phone flawlessly! Hope this helps someone!